# jquery flippy - stoping the flip happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm using a flippy jquery plugin http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/ which is great but when the element flips I want to have a button on the flip side which the user can click and get taken to a different page.

The trouble is that any div in the flip side of the element when it gets clicked causes the flipping to happen again.

I need some way of stopping the flip happening if the user has clicked a div inside the flipped element

http://jsfiddle.net/hw7rP/2/

```
<div class="left bigbox sponsor">
    <div class="sponsorFlip">
        the front
    </div>

    <div class="sponsorData">
        <div class="ifIgetClickedDontFlip">click me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.sponsorFlip').bind("click",function(){
    // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):
    var elem = $(this);
    // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:
    if(elem.data('flipped'))
    {
        // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
        // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:
        elem.revertFlip();
        // Unsetting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',false)
    }
    else
    { // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:
        elem.flip({
            direction:'lr',
            speed: 350,
            color: '#000',
            onBefore: function(){
                // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
                // from view with display:none) into the clicked
                // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
            },
            onEnd: function(){
                //iniatiate ajax requests every second
            }
        });
        // Setting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',true);
    }
});
```

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

After flipping if you want to redirect to some other page, when you again click on the page or button you can do this.

```
$('.sponsorFlip').bind("click",function(){
    // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):
    var elem = $(this);
    // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:
    if(elem.data('flipped'))
    {
      // If the element has already been flipped

      // Write your code here to redirect it to some other page.

     }else{ // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:
           elem.flip({
           direction:'lr',
           speed: 350,
           color: '#000',
           onBefore: function(){
            // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
            // from view with display:none) into the clicked
            // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                       elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
                      },
              onEnd: function(){
            //iniatiate ajax requests every second
                     }
           });
        // Setting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',true);
     }
});
```

Inside the `if(elem.data(flipped))` you can give code to redirect to the page you need.

Comment: that's not quite what I'm after. The div on the flipped side will contain a link to another page. So it's not that I want a redirect but that I want the inner div to be clickable without the flip happening again

Comment: In the fiddle once the div is flipped again when you click the div is not flipped. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hw7rP/3/ ,this what do you want?

Comment: Hi Logan, not quite. I want to be able to flip the div back round when the user clicks anywhere else on the div apart from the link I want. if they click the link they get taken to another page and the div doesn't flip. Click outside the link but in the div and it revert flips like normal

Answer (score 0):

We can check to see if either the clicked element or any of it's parent have a class of `.doNotFlipMe` and if either of these checks evaluate to true, do not flip.
Simples!

HTML:

```
<div class="left bigbox sponsor">
    <div class="sponsorFlip">the front</div>
    <div class="sponsorData">
        <div>Some other content here
            <div class='doNotFlipMe'><a href="www.somesite.com">click me</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.sponsorFlip').bind("click", function (e) {
        // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):
        var elem = $(this);
        // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:
        if (elem.data('flipped')) {
            // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
            // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:
            targetEl = $(e.target);
            if (targetEl.hasClass('doNotFlipMe') || targetEl.parents('.doNotFlipMe').length) {
                // Do nothing
            } else {
                elem.revertFlip();
                // Unsetting the flag:
                elem.data('flipped', false);
            }
        }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/5EnfW/